# unordered list not separated evenly accross ie7

Tags: html, css

i am trying to spread 4 items evenly across its parent container but for some reason in ie7 the fourth item is pushed onto the next line.  I don't understand how that's possible if I am specifying 25% width for each item.  Here is my html/css:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style>
        html, body, ul, li { padding:0; margin:0; }
        ul { list-style:none outside none; }
        ul li { float:left; height:40px; width:25%; }
        ul li a { display:block; height:20px; padding-top:20px; text-align:center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="overflow:hidden">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="b">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="c">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="d">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems to work fine in other browsers, but not ie7.

Comment: Please put a fiddle also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309964/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-7-bug-when-using-percentage-widths-for-layout). Basically IE rounds up when you use percentage widths so it's possible to go over 100% where it will just bump your last item down. So to fix that you should either use 24% instead of 25% or just figure the right px width.

It's a <strike>bit</strike> lot less nice but you could change your code like so:

#### CSS

```
 ul { list-style:none; position:relative; }
 li { position:absolute; top:0; height:40px; width:25%;}
 li.two {left:25%;}
 li.three {left:50%;}
 li.four {left:75%;}
```

#### HTML

```
<div> <!-- removed the overflow:hidden -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a">A</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="b">B</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="c">C</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="d">D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which works for me in IE7 and Chrome

Comment: Yes it seems this question was asked already, not sure why I couldn't find it when I was searching. Interesting solution. You're right, it's less nice, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

If you resize your browser you will probably find that sometimes the last item is on the first line as you want. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310448/637889) to [How to fix Internet explorer 7 bug when using percentage widths for layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309964/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-7-bug-when-using-percentage-widths-for-layout) explains what the problem is.