# If my browser support matrix allows me to use flexbox for layout, should anything be using the float property?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

First I want to reference this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419082/flexbox-vs-tables-why-do-we-need-flexbox), which doesn't quite answer my question. I'm working on a web project which only intends to support evergreen browsers. We're used to using bootstrap, but it seems like we're pulling in a lot of unnecessary CSS Rules given our support matrix.

Are there good/any reasons to use the CSS float property instead of flexbox properties? Is using the float property considered deprecated, for lack of a better word?

Comment: If "evergreen" means what I think it means, then yes, by all means use float rather than flexbox.

Comment: Can you wrap text around diferent sized blocks using flexbox ?

Comment: @MrLister, "evergreen" was intended to be synonymous with "modern" in this case, and can I assume you meant use **flexbox** rather than **float**?

Comment: @vals, I don't think so, but I'll try to work up a fiddle and post it here.

Comment: @bodine Sorry, I didn't associate "evergreen" with "modern". In that case, the answer is that `float` still has its uses, e.g. for letting text flow around images; the things that `float` was designed for.

Comment: @MrLister exactly what I said

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, `float` is still useful for its intended purpose: allowing content to wrap around an image or other element.

### Some points to consider:

- [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/dont-use-flexbox-for-page-layout/) claims that `flexbox` should not be used for page layout, due to the fact that content will be rearranged on the page during load *on slow connections.*
- [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/does-flexbox-have-a-performance-problem/) points to some potential performance problems with too many elements with `flexbox` (though he is unable to replicate said problems)
- [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en#use-flexbox-over-older-layout-models) suggests using `flexbox` over older layout models