# how to set two div's height equal with css

Tags: html, css

I want to make to 2 `div`'s height equal, if one is bigger another should stretch to its height. I want to use only `CSS`. Following is my code([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/Q8m4u/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="common">
    lorem ipusm random text just for check
</div>
<div class="common">
    lorem ipusm random text just for check lorem ipusm random text just for check
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.common{
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  width:20%;
  padding:5px;
}
```

This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/Q8m4u/) for this

Comment: It looks like they would have to be contained by a common container and being resized according to that container. For example, inside an invisible div, and have their dimensions set to a percent of the containing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `flexbox` model. Just add a container for the divs. And add `display: flex` to the parent, and `flex: 1` for children.

Edited [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8m4u/4/)

You can find more information about flexbox on http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It's like saying flex:"true".

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either use table:

```
.container{
    display:table;
    border: solid 1px green;
    width: 200px;
}
.common{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    padding:5px;
}
```

[table fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8m4u/7/)

or js:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('.common').each(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(height > maxHeight){
        maxHeight = height;
    }
})

$('.common').each(function(){
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
})
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8m4u/8/)

Comment: which one is advisable to use.. `display:table` or `display:flex`

Comment: flexbox = cool, table = browser support. for your example I would use table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419082/flexbox-vs-tables-why-do-we-need-flexbox

Answer (score -1):

The CSS property that controls the height of the elements is called height.

the height property does not support negative values. If a percentage is indicated, draws on the height of the parent element. If the parent element does not have an explicitly defined height, the auto height value is assigned.

The inherit value indicates that the height of the element is inherited from its parent element. The auto value, which is used if not explicitly set a value for this property indicates that the browser should automatically calculate the height of the element, considering its content and available on the site.

CSS defines two other related properties of the elements height: min-height and max-height.

```
.common{
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width:20%;
  padding:5px;
}
```

more information [Height](http://librosweb.es/css/capitulo_4/anchura_y_altura.html)

Comment: not looking for static height solution. `min-height` has some other roles to play I guess.