# Vertically centering two divs using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I realize that there are numerous questions about how to do this but all of their solutions seem to be unresponsive to my current situation. I have a banner on the top of a site which has two floated columns in it. The right column contains a nav menu which I feel might be the culprit.

I have set up the following jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhd0soL5/1/

```css
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}



.high {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.high .left-col {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.high .left-col p {
  font-size: 140%;
}

.high .right-col {
  width: 67%;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}


.site-nav {
  float: right;
}

.site-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1.5px solid;
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.site-nav ul {
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}

.site-nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

/* This is the clear fix method */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="high group">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
      <p>Company Name</p>
    </div>
    <aside class="right-col">
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul class="group">
          <li><a href="draft1-1.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#methodology">Methodology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you can set the container to `display:flex` with `justify-content:space-between` (items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end line) and `align-items:center` (items are centered in the cross-axis). See the demo below, I simplified the HTML slightly.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdsyhw5d/)**

```css
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.site-logo {
  font-size: 150%;
}
.site-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.site-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1.5px solid;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 14px 0 0;
}
.site-nav li:last-child {
  border: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="site-logo">Company Name</div>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="draft1-1.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#methodology">Methodology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any cons to using flexbox as opposed to a table solution?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419082/flexbox-vs-tables-why-do-we-need-flexbox But that post is outdated, flexbox supports are pretty good now if you don't care about outdated browsers.

Comment: I've really became a big fan of flexbox since this post and wanted to thank you for turning me on to them. For those looking to learn the two best resources I have found are https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and a set of videos by Wes Bos at flexbox.io

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `display: table` on the parent element, and then `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on each of the 2 children.

This implementation does not use the `float` property.

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhd0soL5/2/)

Like this:

```css
/* line 45, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}


/* line 90, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.high {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
/* line 92, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.high .left-col {
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
/* line 95, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.high .left-col p {
  font-size: 140%;
}
/* line 99, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.high .right-col {
  width: 70%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}

/* line 108, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.site-nav {
  float: right;
}
/* line 110, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.site-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1.5px solid;
}
/* line 116, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.site-nav li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
/* line 120, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.site-nav ul {
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
/* line 124, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.site-nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

/* This is the clear fix method */
/* line 410, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

/* line 415, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 419, ../scss/screen1-2.scss */
.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="high group">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
      <p>Company Name</p>
    </div>
    <aside class="right-col">
      <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul class="group">
          <li><a href="draft1-1.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html" class="last">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#methodology">Methodology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I changed the widths on each elements from 33% and 67% respectively to 30% and 70% because the navbar didn't fit.

Comment: This seems to make everything in the container div to be less than 940 px which was the use of this div. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: Yes, you set the `containter` to have `max-width: 940px`. Therefore, it will only take the minimum needed width. Change it instead to `width: 940px` and it will force it to that.