# Aligning text input with the submit button

Tags: css, textinput

How would this be done?

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/59/

They are both the same height, but they are uneven.

[image]

**Which of these would get:**

vertical-align: top;

vertical-align: bottom;

or would I use it on only one of them?

**That, or would I be using**

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0059dd;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 31px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <input id="input" type="text" name="someNameHere" placeholder="someValueHere" />
  <input id="sent" type="submit" value="Set" />
</div>
```

Comment: I did that here and it messed it up: https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/22/

Comment: You should use flex property on `.info` since flex is capable of solving these kinds of issues where maybe some child element is not filling up the space as it is supposed to. here's a good explanation: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#post-21059

Comment: What if I used  vertical-align: bottom; instead? https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/27/

Comment: I noticed you have `margin-top:30px;` on the input. You should remove that and add it to `.info` instead.

Comment: How come after I did that, it's not doing anything? It's not working in the code, how come? https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/31/

Comment: because you still have `display:table-cell` on `.info` you should have `display:flex;` instead.

Comment: adding in that messes up the whole code.

Comment: update the jsfiddle and send link. idk what you're doing :D

Comment: What if I used table instead?  display: table; https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/37/

Comment: Read this answer (why it should be flex instead of table ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419722/6212957

Comment: Before flex added: https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/37/ / after flex added https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/39/

Comment: yes, you'll need to have margin `.info * { margin-left:2.5px; }`

Comment: What if I removed display from .info, maybe it's not needed? What do you think? https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/53/

Comment: in that case you will have to deal with vertical alignment issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.info {display:flex}

input[type=text] {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #0059dd;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
}

input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0059dd;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid #0059dd;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6q352ysx/11/

Comment: You should give an explanation to why flexbox works in this case.