# Elements do not display inline

Tags: html, css

I have two **`div`** elements styled with the following properties:

```
.elem1 {
    width: 47.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.elem2 {
    width: 47.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Note**: If I reduce the margins to **`2.25%`** **the elements are positioned inline when the parent is the** **`body`**. If then I wrap them into a another **`div`** that is narrower the second element breaks to the following line again.

Since the total amounts to **`100%`** of the parent's **`width`** **why are the elements not positioned inline** and how can I fix this issue, **so that they are positioned inline at all times**?

I essentially want to ***float*** them without using the **`float`** property.

You can check out the following fiddles for a better visual representation:

- [The parent element is the **`body`**.](https://jsfiddle.net/6ugefk4p/)
- [The parent element is the **`body`** and the margin is reduced to **`2.35%`**.](https://jsfiddle.net/6ugefk4p/1/)
- [The parent element is another **`div`** that has **`75%`** of the body's **`width`**.](https://jsfiddle.net/6ugefk4p/3/)

It is necessary that the solution is within CSS only and only in the two **`elem`** elements as there may not be a parent container set by the user.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698636/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I ended up in favour of using **a negative margin** since as of currently it's **the most supported way** contrary to other good, working solutions provided (**`font-size: 0;`**, **`display: flex`**).

In order to make it work I added the following:

```
.elem2 {
    margin-left: calc(2.5% - 4px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements allow regular text to be written so because of the line-break, it is assumed that you added a space in between the div elements. This causes the extra space in-between the div elements which leads to the div elements not fitting in the same line. I usually add a comment in between the elements to override this behavior as well as serve as a reminder to myself and others who may look at the code.

```
<div class="elem1" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div><!--
   This comment is added to prevent space in-between these elements.
--><div class="elem2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer unexpectedly works, but I can't modify the HTML. I need a CSS only solution.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Ah, I didn't see that part of the requirement.

Comment: @AngelPolitis How about setting the font-size of the body tag to be 0px? It may not be idea but what from the sounds of your question, it sounds like you're allowing users to have access to these elements which is not ideal either.

Comment: Setting **`font-size`** to **`0`** has some unexpected behaviour in some browsers (Opera, Android). I am going to keep it in the back of my mind though.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block;` have some space after by default.
To remove it, use `font-size: 0` for `.container`

Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/6ugefk4p/7/).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.elem1 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.elem2 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem1" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="elem2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) is a great article about this spaces between lines of text.

Comment: **Your answer doesn't work**. I want the margin between them to **`2.5%`**, not **`2.25`**. I just made it **`2.25%`** to show that with a smaller margin they would be inline.

Comment: @AngelPolitis changed to `2.5%` - everything works. https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/6ugefk4p/10

Comment: Setting **`font-size`** to **`0`** has some unexpected behaviour in some browsers aka Opera and Android. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the browser support, you can add `display: flex` to the containing element. In this example, I put it on the `body`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.elem1 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.elem2 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem1" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
<div class="elem2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
```

It works with your third example too. I added `display: flex` to `.container`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.elem1 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.elem2 {
  width: 47.5%;
  margin-right: 2.25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem1" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
  <div class="elem2" style="height: 50px; background-color: black;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is a very good option, but probably for future use as it's not currently as widely supported.