# Place two images side by side

Tags: css, image, image-size, responsive-images

I am trying to place two images side by side. I want them to be full width and responsive. However, I can't figure out how to get them on the same line. Does anyone have solutions? Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0je558ex/

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">

  <div class="food-featured-posts-first">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2855/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpg"/ >
  </div>


  <div class="food-featured-posts-second">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg"/ >
  </div>

</div>
```

```html
food-featured-posts {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.food-featured-posts-first img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display:inline-block
}
.food-featured-posts-second img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: Does this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680030/align-images-side-by-side-in-html) help with what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Set the divs that wrap the image to `width: 50%; display: inline-block;` and set the `img` tags to `width: 100%;` so they will take up the entire div, then remove the space between the inline-block div elements in your HTML since spaces on inline elements take up space and the space will exceed 100% width (since each div takes up 50%).

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.food-featured-posts > div {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">
  <div class="food-featured-posts-first">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2855/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpg"/ >
  </div><div class="food-featured-posts-second">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg"/ >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems actually.

First, you're setting the styling of the `img`, but the div which wraps them are implicitly styled to basically be: `display:block;width:100%;`.

Simply remove the `div`s.

Second, and slightly more interestingly, your `img` elements still will not render next to each other at 50% because any whitespace between two `display:inline-block` elements means that the total size is greater than 100%, so the second element is kicked to the second line.

You therefore need to put the `img` tags *on the same line*—frustrating, I know.

See this question: [CSS two div width 50% in one line with line break in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698636/css-two-div-width-50-in-one-line-with-line-break-in-file)

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">
  <!-- Note these are on the same line -->
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2855/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpg"/ ><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg"/ >
</div>
```

```css
food-featured-posts {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.food-featured-posts img {
  width: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```