# How to place two divs on one bottom line?

Tags: html, css

I want my second div to be on the same position with the first one. If text above first blue box is longer, than my second div appears like it off the box line. Changing relative position would not make it better, if the text above blue box would be shorter, than second box appears more below and it looks awful. All values changed dynamically, that why i need not just change position manually.

[image]

```css
.char-span {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.bot-char-all {
    margin-top: -10px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 120px;
}

.bot-char {
    padding-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

char {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.char-pre {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #192E7B;
}
.box-vals {
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.char, .char-value {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.char-pre-val.snow-val {
    background: #CFD1AF;
}
.char-pre-val {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}
.char-val-span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bot-column'>

  <div class='bot-char-val'>
    <div class='bot-char-all'>
      <div class='bot-char'>
        <div class='char'><span class='char-span'>Charakteristischer Wert der Schneelast</span>
          <div class='char-pre snow'><span id='snowLoad-print' class='char-val-span long'>s<sub>k</sub> = 0.85 kN/m<sup>2</sup></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='box-vals'>
      <div class='char-value'><span class='char-span'>Snow</span>
        <div class='char-pre-val snow-val'> <span id='snowLoadZone-print' class='char-val-span'>2*</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS two div width 50% in one line with line break in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698636/css-two-div-width-50-in-one-line-with-line-break-in-file) or [any of these?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=two+divs+one+line)

Answer (score 2):

This is classic CSS aligment with flex.

Try adding the following to .bot-char-val:

```css
.bot-char-val {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

And remove floats and margins from:

```css
.box-vals {
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bot-char-all {
  float: none;
}
```

```css
.char-span {
    font-size: 13px !important;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.bot-char-all {
    margin-top: -10px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 120px;
}

.bot-char {
    padding-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

char {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.char-pre {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #192E7B;
}
.box-vals {
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.char, .char-value {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.char-pre-val.snow-val {
    background: #CFD1AF;
}
.char-pre-val {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}
.char-val-span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}

.box-vals {
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bot-char-all {
  float: none;
}
.bot-char-val {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='bot-column'>

  <div class='bot-char-val'>
    <div class='bot-char-all'>
      <div class='bot-char'>
        <div class='char'><span class='char-span'>Charakteristischer Wert der Schneelast</span>
          <div class='char-pre snow'><span id='snowLoad-print' class='char-val-span long'>s<sub>k</sub> = 0.85 kN/m<sup>2</sup></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='box-vals'>
      <div class='char-value'><span class='char-span'>Snow</span>
        <div class='char-pre-val snow-val'> <span id='snowLoadZone-print' class='char-val-span'>2*</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: mmm... It is the same

Comment: No its not. I added changes at the bottom of the CSS, run code snippet and you will see.

Comment: Snippet shows me the same result as i have in my version.

Comment: Its impossible, I added two classes. Click on run code snippet, this is not the same as you have. I even wrote the css you need to add at the top of my answer.

Comment: This classes were added: .box-vals {
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bot-char-all {
  float: none;
}
.bot-char-val {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: end;
}

Comment: @NarJovan said the truth your code snippet show the exact example as the question. See by yourself

Comment: Oh my god, this is crazy, you guys know you can scroll ? I added three classes on the CSS section. :D

Comment: It was a mistake,  align-items: end; should be  align-items: flex-end; I was testing on FF. So yeah, I got that bad. I apology :)

Comment: When I first got it, it was wrong but now it works @avcajaraville.

Comment: @NarJovan for IE > 11 yep, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display flex` to `parent` and     `align-self: flex-end;` to `child` will solve your problem.

```css
.char-span {
  font-size: 13px !important;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.bot-char-all {
  margin-top: -10px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.bot-char {
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: left;
}

char {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.char-pre {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #192E7B;
}

.box-vals {
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.char,
.char-value {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.char-pre-val.snow-val {
  background: #CFD1AF;
}

.char-pre-val {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.char-val-span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.box-vals {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bot-char-all {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.bot-char-val {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='bot-column'>

  <div class='bot-char-val'>
    <div class='bot-char-all'>
      <div class='bot-char'>
        <div class='char'><span class='char-span'>Charakteristischer Wert der Schneelast</span>
          <div class='char-pre snow'><span id='snowLoad-print' class='char-val-span long'>s<sub>k</sub> = 0.85 kN/m<sup>2</sup></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='box-vals'>
      <div class='char-value'><span class='char-span'>Snow</span>
        <div class='char-pre-val snow-val'> <span id='snowLoadZone-print' class='char-val-span'>2*</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example with [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Grundlegende_Konzepte_der_Flexbox):

```css
.bot-column {
  max-width: 220px; /* for demo purposes */
}

.bot-char-val {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bot-char-all, 
.box-vals {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
}

.char-pre {
  border: 2px solid #192E7B;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

.char-pre-val {
  background: #CFD1AF;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='bot-column'>
  <div class='bot-char-val'>
  
    <div class='bot-char-all'>
      <div class='bot-char'>
        <div class='char'><span class='char-span'>Charakteristischer Wert der Schneelast</span>
          <div class='char-pre snow'><span id='snowLoad-print' class='char-val-span long'>s<sub>k</sub> = 0.85 kN/m<sup>2</sup></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='box-vals'>
      <div class='char-value'><span class='char-span'>Snow</span>
        <div class='char-pre-val snow-val'> <span id='snowLoadZone-print' class='char-val-span'>2*</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```