# How can I put two <div> that has the same width and height next to each other without having to scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a simple html page with two sections with content inside of each of them but the last content of the second div `.right` is going on the bottom of the page and make the page scrollable.

I tried making another div and put a `flex-direction: column` but it doesn't work:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>content should be on top</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I put two `<div>` that has the same width and height next to each other without having to scroll?

Comment: `flex-direction: column` makes the children line up in a column; in other words, one on top of the other, which sounds the opposite of what you want -- remove that. Instead of `width`, try using `flex-basis: 50%`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS two div width 50% in one line with line break in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698636/css-two-div-width-50-in-one-line-with-line-break-in-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `flex-direction: row` and not `flex-direction: column`.

To avoid repeating `width: 50%; height: 100vh;` for both `.left` and `.right`, I would also create another class, such as `.box`, which is applied to both and contains these properties.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  background: #ecece9;
}

.right {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left box">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right box">
    <h2>content should be on top</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the flex direction from column to row

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>content should be on top</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Grid to build Layouts it is very powerful. See I changed only two lines and the layout is ready.

```
   .main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%
}

.left {
  background: #ecece9;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="left">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h2>content should be on top</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only display flex on large screen and and block on mobile

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background: #ecece9;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding:20px;
}

.right {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding:20px;
}

/* For mobile screen 
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-container{
    display: block;
  }
  .left, .right{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="left">
      <h2>content</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h2>content should be on top</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
```