# Align two Div Boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css

I need to display four checkbox as following

```
        A           B
        C           D
```

There should be two in each line? 
Can anyone suggest what would be right css for this? They need to be inside  or combination of Div

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: So those A B C D are 4 divs, where each division contains "1 checkbox + 1 text description"?

Comment: You can put each box in div, there will be 2 kinds of divs, the one is `float:left` and the other is `float:right`, you give them some width and that's it!

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/fN8Mz/

Comment: there must be 1000 answers to this question on this site

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a fixed file and doesn't need to be content-managed, I'd use columns for ease of use. If it needs to be content-managed and the content is likely to change then I'd go for dealing with rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/FUJMS/5/

HTML:

```
<html>

    <div class="column one">
        <div class="box A"></div>
        <div class="box C"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="column two">
       <div class="box B"></div>
       <div class="box D"></div>
   </div>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.column {
    width:50%;
}

div.column.one {
    float:left;
}

div.column.two {
    float:right;
}

div.box {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: There is no column two in css

Comment: I know, it should fill the space by - and be brought in line with - the floated element. Now that you've mentioned it I'm starting to doubt myself, either way the second would just need a float applied.

Comment: Done, just needed the float as I said. I'd missed a ';' after the widths, which threw me a bit.

Comment: Okami, why do you use two classes: "box A"? Did you mean "boxA" or "box_A", didn't you? Or what sense makes those classes?

Comment: So you can apply a generic class for them all tp save CSS, but differentiate them if need be through the letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
  .item {white-space: nowrap;display:inline; }
</style>
<fieldset>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">a</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <input type="checkbox" id="b">

    <label for="b">b</label>
</div>
<br/> //link break or anything you like
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">c</label>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c">
    <label for="c">D</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

This should work for you with slight minor changes if you feel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to put the checkbox inside the label tag

```html
<label for="cb1"><input id="cb1" name="cb1" type="checkbox" /> checkbox1 </label>
<label for="cb2"><input id="cb2" name="cb2" type="checkbox" /> checkbox2 </label>
<label for="cb3"><input id="cb3" name="cb3" type="checkbox" /> checkbox3 </label>
<label for="cb4"><input id="cb4" name="cb4" type="checkbox" /> checkbox4 </label>
```

and stylize it as follows

```css
label {
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    *width:49%; /*for IE7 only*/
    float:left;
}
label[for="cb3"] {
    clear:left;
}
```

Thanks to Liam for calling attention to this SO question: [Should I put input tag inside label tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag).
Now the answer is compatible with screenreaders and IE7.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUJMS/6/)

Comment: Is this a good idea? I'm not convinced a label should contain an input

Comment: Yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774054/should-i-put-input-tag-inside-label-tag. But it feels dirty to me...

Comment: I wasn't aware that putting anything inside a `<label>` was valid. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Also one question related to IE7 pixel-width-rounding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309964/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-7-bug-when-using-percentage-widths-for-layout#1310448